# Ionic does not navigate to specified URL after push notification

Tags: typescript, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, ionic4

I have an ionic chat app that receives push notifications from firebase cloud functions...you click the icon and the app open.  The problem is it's not navigating to the specified page when the notification is received in the background, only in the foreground.

Here's my app component:

```js
  initializeApp() {
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    }

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user => {
          if (!user) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
            unsubscribe();
          } else {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('tabs');
            unsubscribe();
          }
        });
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.getDeviceToken();
    });
  }

  getDeviceToken() {
    this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
      if (data.wasTapped) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('tabs/connections');

        console.log("Received in background", data.wasTapped);
      } else {
        console.log("Received in foreground", data.wasTapped);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('tabs/connections');
      }
    });

    this.fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token => {
      // Register your new token in your back-end if you want
      this.fcmService.saveTokenToFirestore(token, this.loggedInUser.uid);
    });
  }
```

if the app is open and it receives a push notification in the foreground it will navigate to the specified page, but not when it's closed.

I doubt these errors that appear when I open the app has anything to do with it...they were there before push notifications and they haven't encumbered any functionality...just thought it was worth mentioning:

```js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
polyfills.js:3040 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error Status 404: App not found ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Error Status 404: App not found
    at IonicDeployImpl.<anonymous> (/plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic/dist/common.js:291)
    at step (/plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic/dist/common.js:37)
    at Object.next (/plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic/dist/common.js:18)
    at fulfilled (/plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic/dist/common.js:9)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (polyfills.js:2749)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (polyfills.js:2508)
    at polyfills.js:3247
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:2781)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (polyfills.js:2553)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (polyfills.js:2959) Error: Error Status 404: App not found
    at IonicDeployImpl.<anonymous> (http://localhost/plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic/dist/common.js:291:35)
    at step (http://localhost/plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic/dist/common.js:37:23)
    at Object.next (http://localhost/plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic/dist/common.js:18:53)
    at fulfilled (http://localhost/plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic/dist/common.js:9:58)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost/polyfills.js:2749:26)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (http://localhost/polyfills.js:2508:43)
    at http://localhost/polyfills.js:3247:34
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost/polyfills.js:2781:31)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost/polyfills.js:2553:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost/polyfills.js:2959:35)
```

Otherwise, I'm not getting any errors in the console.  ALSO, it's not console logging "console.log("Received in background", data.wasTapped);"

It will console.log "console.log("Received in foreground", data.wasTapped);"

Again, this is Ionic 4 with Firebase...any help would be greatly appreciated.

I was able to at least the console to log the data was tapped = true.  But now I'm getting this error:

Navigation triggered outside Angular zone, did you forget to call 'ngZone.run()'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured this out.  I'm using a tabs module. So in order to get this working I had to put the fcm.onNotification in the main tabs module.  Now it works when the app is in the background

Comment: Hi, can you explain more how you solved this? I'm currently facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue.
But then I tried sending notification using https://cordova-plugin-fcm.appspot.com/ .
So after sending notification from the given link, when I clicked to the notification it redirected to the desired page.
So I came to know that there was no issue in my code but there is issue in code of sending notification.
For more go through this article https://enappd.com/blog/implement-ionic-4-firebase-push/34/